# Issue with building Android App in Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

On trying to build the Android app for my ionic project I get the error stack trace below

> C:\Users\Peter Okocici\WebstormProjects\Pido\pido-project\pido\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\drawable-hdpi-icon.png: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

I have spent hours on this, no matter what I do this error stays.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.pido480170" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <name>pido</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
</widget>
```

Find above the config file

Comment: Delete your 2 folders(icons and splash) from resource/andoid directory and run  ionic resources from termnal

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that `drawable-hdpi-icon.png` is not a valid filename. Android resource filenames cannot contain hyphens (`-`) - only lower case letters, numbers and underscores. Rename your file and you should be good.

Comment: I am not the one generating the file as soon as I change it and run ionic build android, all the files get overwritten and the error happens again

Comment: Are you copying the icon over using the `<icon... >` directive in your `config.xml`?

Comment: I am not copying anything, I just run ionic add platform android, then run ionic build android

Comment: Please add your `config.xml` contents to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Move your project to a new folder where there are no spaces in the directory

e.g C:\WebstormProjects\Pido\